# How do I add a string to a variable called from a CSV file before it is called in a function?

Tags: powershell, networking

I am trying to ping a list of IPs, but I need to test variations of them for RACs and KVMs. I want to take the IP address (in the `$ColumnHeader` variable) and append "rac" to it before pinging it. I also will need to ping "arac", "raca", "kv", "akv", "kva", and "kvm", but I was just going to substitute those manually into the script after running it each time.

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, position=0)][string]$csvfile
)

$ColumnHeader = "Name"
#$string = "rac"
#$subServer = "$($ColumnHeader)$($string)"

Write-Host "Reading file" $csvfile
$ipaddresses = Import-Csv $csvfile | Select-Object $ColumnHeader

Write-Host "Started Pinging.."
foreach ($ip in $ipaddresses) {
    if (Test-Connection $ip.($ColumnHeader) -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Write-Host $ip.("Name") "Ping succeeded." -Foreground Green
    } else {
        Write-Host $ip.("Name") "Ping failed." -Foreground Red
    }
}

Write-Host "Pinging Completed."
```

I've tried creating new variables `$string` and `$subServer` and using those in place of `$ColumnHeader` on line 14, but I get a "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'." error.

EDIT: I changed Line 7 from `$subServer = $ColumnHeader + $string` to `$subServer = "$($ColumnHeader)$($string)"`, and I can successfully call `$subServer` on Line 14 in place of `$ColumnHeader`, but when I uncomment `$string` on Line 6, I get the aforementioned 'ComputerName' error again.

Comment: So, the `$ipaddresses` variable doesn't actually contain IP addresses, it contains hostnames, correct?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen correct. I got the main body of the script from https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/powershell/131/ping-list-of-ips.html and have been trying to modify it for my purposes.

Comment: Line 38 is the `Test-Connection` statement? Because the code snippet you posted doesn't have 38 lines.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers ah, my bad. The full code has several lines of comments above it. It's Line 14 here.

Comment: Neither `$subServer` nor `$server` are used anyhwere in your code. Please create a [mcve], test-run *that* code, then update your question with *that* code and the full error the code produced. Also include sample input.